# Find a coefficient of quadratic polynomial, given the sum of its root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

The sum of the zeros of $f(x) = x^2 − 3kx − 14$ is $3$. Find $k$.

How can I start this question?

Comment: The sum of the roots of a second degree polynomial $ax^2+bc+c$ is $-b/a$

Answer (score 2):

The sum of zeros is the opposite of the coefficient of X, so that... $k$ is equal to $1$. Expand $(X-r_1)(X-r_2)$ to convince yourself.

Comment: Even more specifically, if you know of Newton's identities, this generalizes to polynomials of arbitrary degree.  When $f(x)=x^n-s_1 x^{n-1}+s_2 x^{n-2}+\dots\pm s_{n-1}x\mp s_n$ then $s_1 = $ the sum of the roots.  (*note* it is the coefficient of the second largest ordered term, not necessarily the coefficient of the $x^1$ term)

Answer (score 1):

let $x_1,x_2$ be the roots of equation $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ from Viete formulas $$x_1+x_2=-b/a,x_1x_2=c/a$$ in your equation $a=1,b=-3k,c=-14$ then $$x_1+x_2=-(-3k)/1=3k$$
because $3k=3$ follow that $k=1$

Comment: Please improve the clarity of your answer, "Vieta", define $x_1,x_2$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Vieta's formulae.$$$$